# Jasper report expression evaluation

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a report that evaluates values and checks if the conditions are correct, if yes it is a  success and the report returns Pass

However the equation needs to be modified

Current equation is

```
($F{SPECPASS}.equals($F{SPECS}) ? "Pass" : "Fail")
```

I want the new equation to be something like this

```
If SPECPASS/SPECS >=0.5, then STATUS = ‘Pass’, Otherwise STATUS = ‘Fail’
```

I am new to Jasper reports and the version we have is 3.6.0

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I think, we can use

```
(($F{SPECPASS}.doubleValue() / $F{SPECS}.doubleValue() >=0.5) ?"Pass":"Fail")
```

Comment: This works however in the expression box I see that there is a red underline for this expression, but compilation is correct and it works